# trouble with variable in Range.select

Tags: vba, excel, select, range

Can anyone give me a clue as to why I can't seem to get a variable to function in my Range.select?

As you can see from the commented statements I have tried a number of different syntax's and commands but I always get a run-time error 1004, method Range of object global failed

I am trying to take data from sheet one in a specific section and copy it to specific cells in the current row (by loop count) in sheet two. Ignore the unfinished loop, haven't been able to get it to run through once so i haven't completed writing the loop yet.

```
Sub PutDataSht2()

Dim rowVal As Integer
rowVal = 1

'
' PutDataSht2
'
'
    'ThisWorkbook.Activate

    'Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A38:H38").Select
    Selection.Copy
    'Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    'Range("A1:H1").Select
    Range("A[XrowVal]:H[XrowVal]").Select
    'Range("A & rowVal:H & rowVal").Select
    'Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A & rowVal:H & rowVal")
    'ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, rowVal), Cells(8, rowVal)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B85:H85").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    'Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    'Range("J1:P1").Select
    Range("J & rowVal:P & rowVal").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B132:D132").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    'Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    'Range("R1:T1").Select
    Range("R & rowVal:T & rowVal").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    rowVal = (rowVal + 1)

End Sub
```

`

Comment: Forgot to mention that I can get it to work with the explicit Range("R1:T1").Select type of command just not with variables.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't have to select something to copy it with VBA. For example, instead of the two statements `Range("A38:H38").Select` and `Selection.Copy`, you could simply write `Range("A38:H38").Copy`. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your options is almost correct!

```
Range("A & rowVal:H & rowVal").Select
```

should be:

```
Range("A" & rowVal & ":H" & rowVal).Select
```